# Ruby on Rails: Spam Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm looking for a gem for my app that will prevent spamming the comments section.

So, Rails validations work fine, but when a user would spam and type the same letter say 1000 times-it would go through and obviously mess up the entire app and css structure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Akismet for Wordpress blog. Works perfectly.
There is ruby gem also https://github.com/jonahb/akismet